# How to move my player sprite?

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code. How can I move my class `Player` sprite? Would I add an x,y to my `def __init__`? like `def __init__(self, x, y)`? Thanks for the answers,

```
import pygame as pg
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

CLOCK = pg.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
LIGHTBLUE = (20, 130, 230)
BGCOLOR = LIGHTBLUE

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ((WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

player = Player()

pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption('The Moon Smiles Back')

running = True
while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites.add(player)
    all_sprites.update()
    screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pg.display.flip()

    CLOCK.tick(FPS)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Please don't just add random letters so that your post is not mostly code.

Comment: Fix code and title.

Answer (score 0):

Add two attributes to the `Player` class to store the current velocity of the player. In the `update` method, add the velocities to the `x` and `y` attributes and then set the rect to the new position.

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.velocity_x = 0
        self.velocity_y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.velocity_x
        self.y += self.velocity_y
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
```

To move the player to the right, set the `player.velocity_x` to the desired speed if the 'd' key is pressed (in this example), and back to 0 if the key is released. Do the same for the other directions.

```
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
        running = False
    elif event.key == pg.K_d:
        player.velocity_x = 3
elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pg.K_d:
        player.velocity_x = 0
```

Comment: In your update function, you can also simply use `self.rect.move_ip(self.velocity_x, self.velocity_x)`

Comment: I'd use `rect.move_ip` or `rect.x += speed` only for the simplest games. The problem is that it only works correctly with integers (floats are truncated) and if you eventually want to make the game frame rate independent you have to multiply the velocity by delta time and thus have to deal with floats. I'd actually use vectors for the position and velocity, but tried to keep the code a bit simpler. So the example is just a first step in the right direction.

Comment: Fair point. It's sad that pygame provides vector classes but the entire `Sprite`/`Group`/`Rect` system makes no use of them; so you would have to manually change a Sprite's rect to match your position vector. It would be nice if the Sprite class could automatically handle that......

Comment: Yeah, I've actually already thought about suggesting something like that for the new pygame version (which should use SDL2). But it seems the devs want to keep everything completely backwards compatible and I'm not sure if it would break existing code and how it would affect the performance, etc.